# Excel Add ins not accessing the Internet when we are behind proxy

Tags: macos, http-proxy, excel-addins

Can anyone tell me why excel add ins not accessing internet when we set proxy in Mac. Otherwise it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

this based on how you access the internet in your code.

if you machine have a proxy, you need appedn the proxy to you httpclient(something like this too) to get data.

sometimes the code maybe like:

```
HttpClientHandler handler;
handler.Proxy = GetProxy(url, "systemproxy");//custom function to get proxy
```

there is a API to get the system proxy. yeah, proxy have many cases, you maybe need check all the proxy type.

```
  public static extern bool WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(
        IntPtr hSession,
        string lpcwszUrl,
        ref WINHTTP_AUTOPROXY_OPTIONS pAutoProxyOptions,
        ref WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO pProxyInfo);
```